# Complex object value parse

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've got an objects like:

```
var exampleObject = {
    listItem1: 1,
    subList: {
        subSubList: {
            subSubListItem1: 1,
            subSubListItem2: 'green'
        },
        subListItem1: 'blue'
    }
};
```

Values of this object can be numbers, strings, arrays and another objects. I need to get string paths array to the key-value pare where value equals to number 1. For exampleObject it's:

```
[
    "listItem1",
    "subList > subSubList > subSubListItem1"
]
```

How can I recieve this array from all objects of that structure using only JavaScript?

Comment: push to a array

Comment: What if there's a property like: `subList: [{x : 1}, {x: 1}]`, how would that be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the item is an object and iterate the keys. If not, then an end is found and the actual path is added to the result set.

```js
function getPath(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
            });
        } else if (o === 1){
            result.push(p.join(' > '));
        }
    }
  
    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result;
}

var exampleObject = { listItem1: 1, subList: { subSubList: { subSubListItem1: 1, subSubListItem2: 'green' }, subListItem1: 'blue' } };

console.log(getPath(exampleObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...in` recursively. Here's the [mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
function getNext( obj ){
   for( var val in obj ){
      if( typeof obj[val] === 'object' )
         return val + ' > ' + getNext( obj[val] );
      else if( obj[val] === 1 ){
         delete obj[val];
         return val;
      }
   }
}
var list = [];
while( Object.keys( exampleObject ).length > 0 )
  list.push( getNext( exampleObject );

list.filter( function( x ){ return x[ x.length - 1 ] === ' '; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function using `for...in` loop.

```js
var exampleObject = {
  listItem1: 1,
  subList: {
    subSubList: {
      subSubListItem1: 1,
      subSubListItem2: 'green'
    },
    subListItem1: 'blue'
  }
};

function getKeys(data, val) {
  var result = [];

  function inner(data, val, keys) {
    for (var i in data) {
      if (data[i] == val) result.push((keys + ' > ' + i).substr(3))
      if (typeof data[i] == 'object' && inner(data[i], val, keys + ' > ' + i)) {
        result = result.concat(inner(data[i], val, keys + ' > ' + i))
      }

    }
  }
  inner(data, val, '')
  return result
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getKeys(exampleObject, 1), 0, 4))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getKeys(exampleObject, 'green'), 0, 4))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getKeys(exampleObject, 'blue'), 0, 4))
```